# Does bgsave save changes after someone key was already written to RDB file?

Tags: redis

During the execution of bgsave, suppose there is a key，and the type of this key is "set". After this set  was written to RDB file, if values in this set changes, (such as someone execute 'sadd key xxx'). Will bgsave write this change to the RDB file？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, it is a point-in-time snapshot.

Redis takes a snapshot of the dataset in the background, e.g. when calling `BGSAVE`, by forking - this allows the persistence process to access the data without copying it. Furthermore, copy-on-write semantics cause the data to be copied when it is written to (e.g. a `SADD` command) by the main process, making the persistence process oblivious of such changes.

More information is at https://redis.io/topics/persistence and http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html.